# How can i do such replace http://site.com/page1/node2 to http://page1.com/node2?

Tags: drupal, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I 'replace' the url for the following links:

`http://site.com/en/Hotel_Mom_Loves/Father` to `http://HotelCartagenaAzul.com/Father`

... with htacess?

Comment: You should also post more or better examples, because what you have posted now lacks any kind of pattern. And is therefore hardly programmable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [htaccess internal rewrite from subdomain to subdir path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21655889/htaccess-internal-rewrite-from-subdomain-to-subdir-path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to make links in such way with **htaccess**.
As solution we can use custom redirect with REGEX based at php.