# htaccess internal rewrite from subdomain to subdir path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns, subdomain

Im at least 24 hours busy on this subject, I cant seem to get this script to work. The script doesnt redirect at all.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.skynet\.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /mobile/final/$1 [L,NC]
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.skynet\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile/final/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobile/final/$1 [L,NC]
```

This partially works, but links like m.skynet.com\download.php wont get redirected

**UPDATE: 45min later**

Now it suddenly works.
But the URL gets rewritten in FireFox, while in Chrome it works properly

**UPDATE**
Seems that the problem with Firefox was caused by a 301-redirect I used earlier, the cache had to be flushed. for it to work properly again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove leading slash from match:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.skynet\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile/final/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobile/final/$1 [L,NC]
```

- `.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path (thus leading slash) from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.
- You need `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile/final/` to prevent looping.

Comment: Seems your solution worked partially, when I enter for example: m.skynet.com/download.php I dont get redirecte to the page in the directory

Comment: Not sure what is special about `/download.php` but this rule will rewrite that to `/mobile/final/download.php`